# ctrl alt t opening ROXTerm

Tags: gnome-terminal

I always use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open my terminal, then it randomly started opening `roxterm` instead of the normal terminal, how do I change it back? Please advise.

Comment: What does the command `update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator` say?

Comment: I'll send it in 2 parts

Comment: x-terminal-emulator - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/roxterm
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper - priority 40
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.1.gz
/usr/bin/koi8rxterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/koi8rxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/lxterm - priority 30
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/lxterm.1.gz

Comment: /usr/bin/roxterm - priority 50
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/roxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/uxterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/uxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/xterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/xterm.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/roxterm'.

Comment: Better to **edit your question** than to add via comments.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to restore the default by running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

and following the on-screen instructions to select `gnome-terminal-emulator` (or `gnome-terminal.wrapper`).

Comment: Have to acknowledge a good answer when I see one :)

Comment: It "worked" for me, but not really: it set the new terminal emulator in manual mode, but the old one is still in auto mode. As a result, the old one still starts up when I hit Ctrl+Alt+T.